# Proof of Levinson-Durbin algorithm

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis

Is there any article or reference book with a full proof of the Levinson-Durbin algorithm used for solving linear system with a Toeplitz matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

See, for example, [these lecture notes,](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-341-discrete-time-signal-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec13.pdf) or, for a more formal exposition, consult [Levinson's Algorithm, Wold's Decomposition, and Spectral Estimation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2031582%0A) by A. Papoulis (1985).